# Obtener valor de celda en DataGridView c# con subindices

Tags: c#

¿Me podrian ayudar diciendome una forma de obtener el valor de una celda especifica por codigo?
Tengo programado para que el usuario al hacer clic sobre cualquier celda se seleccione el renglon completo donde se encuentra esa celda. Entonces los metodos que he encontrado unicamente me regresan el valor de la celda seleccionada, pero en este caso pues se selecciona todo el renglon y solo quiero el valor de la celda 1 de ese renglon seleccionado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La grilla te devuelve un vector de selectedrows. Si transformas eso a row, podes saber cual es el valor de la celda que vos queres ;)

Comment: Echa un vistazo a:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/7ad5b2db-2992-4d61-b07b-70a4b45241ee/como-seleccionar-una-celda-especfica-en-un-datagridview-c?forum=vcses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu evento, primero que nada tienes que sacar el index del renglon y la celda esta puede ser opcional, posteriormente haz lo siguiente:

```
 int cell, row;
                cell = e.ColumnIndex;
                row = e.RowIndex;

    string valor = DataGridView.Rows[row].Cells["NombreDeLaCelda"].Value.ToString();
```

tambien puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera

```
string valor = DataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvio.